# Wamp Server 400 Bad Request Illegal filename error

Tags: wamp

Im setting up my new PC and installed wamp server. When I open the phpMyAdmin this error show on the browser. The error says

400 Bad Request

Illegal filename.

Comment: What's the file name?

Comment: I dont know what file has the illegal file name. The only thing I did was open the phpMyAdmin and the error shows.
1 more thing, the localhost also has an error which says

Authorization Required